# Python 3 figure subplot only shows one plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have the following code for which only ax3 displays the plotting area and data. Subplots ax1 and ax2 display a plot area but no data. Ultimately, I want three plots (3, 1 configuration) with sharex=True. I'm using Python 2.7.2 and matplotlib 1.2.1

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=True, sharey=False)
f.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)

N = 4
ind = np.arange(N)

width = .4
group_names = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')

q2 = [84, 21, 10, 4]
q4 = [69, 34, 22, 0]
q6 = [66, 28, 17, 2]

colors = ['c', 'purple', 'g', 'red']

ax1 = plt.barh(ind, q2, width, color=colors)
plt.yticks(ind+width/N, group_names)
plt.ylim([min(ind)-0.25, max(ind)+0.65])
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 110, 10.))
plt.xlim(0, 100)

ax2 = plt.barh(ind, q4, width, color=colors)
plt.yticks(ind+width/N, group_names)
plt.ylim([min(ind)-0.25, max(ind)+0.65])
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 110, 10.))
plt.xlim(0, 100)

ax3 = plt.barh(ind, q6, width, color=colors)
plt.yticks(ind+width/N, group_names)
plt.ylim([min(ind)-0.25, max(ind)+0.65])
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 110, 10.))
plt.xlim(0, 100)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Why do you use `plt.barh` here? Instead use `ax1.barh`, etc to plot directly to your axis.

Comment: by the way, `matplotlib v1.2.1` is 2 and a half years old. `1.4.3` is the current stable release. You might consider updating your version

Answer (score 1):

You've done something a bit strange. You define `ax1`, `ax2`, and `ax3` at the top of your script with the `plt.subplots` command, but then you don't use them later. I've reworked you script to make sure that all your commands are working on the correct `axes`.

Instead of `plt.barh()`, you can use `ax1.barh()`. Then, you can set the ticks and axes limits using `ax1.set_yticks()`, `ax1.set_ylim()`, `ax1.set_xticks()` and `ax1.set_xlim()`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=True, sharey=False)
f.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)

N = 4
ind = np.arange(N)

width = .4
group_names = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')

q2 = [84, 21, 10, 4]
q4 = [69, 34, 22, 0]
q6 = [66, 28, 17, 2]

colors = ['c', 'purple', 'g', 'red']

ax1.barh(ind, q2, width, color=colors)
ax1.set_yticks(ind+width/N, group_names)
ax1.set_ylim([min(ind)-0.25, max(ind)+0.65])
ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 110, 10.))
ax1.set_xlim(0, 100)

ax2.barh(ind, q4, width, color=colors)
ax2.set_yticks(ind+width/N, group_names)
ax2.set_ylim([min(ind)-0.25, max(ind)+0.65])
ax2.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 110, 10.))
ax2.set_xlim(0, 100)

ax3.barh(ind, q6, width, color=colors)
ax3.set_yticks(ind+width/N, group_names)
ax3.set_ylim([min(ind)-0.25, max(ind)+0.65])
ax3.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 110, 10.))
ax3.set_xlim(0, 100)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
    plt.barh(ind, q2, width, color=colors)
```

change them as

```
    ax1 = ax1.barh(ind, q2, width, color=colors)
    ax2 = ax2.barh(ind, q4, width, color=colors)
    ax3 = ax3.barh(ind, q6, width, color=colors)
```

Hope this solves your problem.